# What is the latest version of Jquery I can use with Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2008

I am new to Jquery and am trying to use it in an ASP.NET web page project to simplify AJAX calls.

I can't seem to get the Jquery script to work reliably in visual studio 2008. I installed the service pack 1 for VS2008, and the hotfix which allows support for .vsdoc support on .js files for intellisense.

I downloaded Jquery from the main site, google, msdn, (ver. 1.8.2) and all of those files give me issues. The issues are: Visual Studio keeps prompting me with the JIT debugger window saying that there was unhandled exception in typebuilder.exe. If I debug it, its highlighting a section of the Jquery file.

Ive read that typebuilder.exe has something to do with intellisense, so I removed my vsdoc file and just have the jquery file. It didnt change anything.

Sometimes I also get an error saying that $ is not recognized, even though I have the script reference in my code.

```
<script src="Scripts/js/jquery-1.8.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Am I not able to create projects using the latest version of Jquery? How can I get this library to work, preferribly with a vsdoc file for intellisense support.

Thanks for any help

Comment: I have tried versions 1.8.1, 1.8.0 as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ill post my solution for others who may run into this.

I managed to find something about my issues. On CodeProject, something posted about the same frustration I am having.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/215666/How-to-fix-Visual-Studio-2008-Intellisense-for-JQu

Turns out, that version 1.4.1 was the last "Tested" version to work with 2008. There are vsdoc files for later versions on the MS CDN but they all seem to be bugged in some fashion to work with 2008. The solution outlined there is to get 1.6.1 to work. I followed it and it all looks good so far. However, i wasnt able to use .min version of 1.6.1 yet.

I guess you could probably fix the other documents for later versions manually, and it would work too, but I am not that proficient in JS to spend time on that.

Ill use 1.6.1 for now.